# Syntax error in mysql when inserting an image into a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mysql and I would really appreciate any help. What I want to do is to upload an image to a specific row in a database and then display the image in the user's page. The error I get is:

> Error in Query:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'WHERE id = 1'` at line 4.

This is the piece of code referenced:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users5 (image, imageName)
        VALUES ('{$imgData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}')WHERE id = $id;";
```

Comment: insert can not have where condition the way you are doing...

Comment: remove WHERE id=$id or use UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO

Comment: Why would anyone have a table called 'something*5*' ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What I want to do is to upload an image to a specific row in a database*

You have to use an `UPDATE` command if a row is already existing.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users5 SET image = ?, imageName = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 'ssi', $imgData, $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $id );
```

As suggested, you better use [*prepared statement to bind parameter*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) values for placeholders safely, avoiding [*SQL injection*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).